# Is it possible to use grunt-watch to watch a folder one level up from the root directory?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm i have two dirs, one for a website, one for tests, i'd like the grunt in tests to listen to changes in the website root and execute a command

it works relative, but, i'm sure there's something wrong with paths here...

```
watch: {
            absolutepathwatch{
                files: setUpDirectoriesAndFiles(config.hdidResources + "/public/scripts/**/*.js"), //me trying to use absolute 'config.path' is the absolute path to the website
                tasks: ['shell:utest']
            },
            relativepathwatch: {
                files: "./../website/public/scripts/**/*.js", //me trying to use relative kind of like "go up one from this root, then go into website, then listen"                 
                tasks: ['shell:utest']
            }
        }
```

Note, i've tried `../../` and `/../../`, neither seem to work.

Any suggestions?